# Why is reputation about 15 minutes behind on meta compared to the normal site?

Tags: support, reputation

For some reason, when I'm on meta, I noticed that reputation changes are a little behind. For example, earlier I edited a post on the main site giving me two more reputation points. Over on the meta site, however, it took 15 minutes more than the main site to load.

Is this a bug?

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference anyways. Either way you still get your reputation. Even if it took a whole day to update, it shouldn't be that big of a deal.

Comment: Reputation is copied once an hour, so it'll be up to an hour behind. See the duplicate FAQ.

Comment: Because caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job that syncs your meta reputation doesn't run every second - that would be far too wasteful. Having a job that runs every 15 minutes (or so) is more than sufficient.

The times when it matters that your meta reputation hasn't synced are so few and far between it's not worth the extra resources it would consume.

Comment: Why is it even necessary to sync reputation? Why not just have the same reputation on both sites, and when reputation is displayed on Meta load the number directly from the main site?

Comment: @DonaldDuck it's because the sites are separate - separate questions, answers, users and votes.